# Isabelle: Wellsortedness error

Tags: isabelle

What is the Wellsortedness error in Isabelle.

I encountered a trouble such as:
[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` command internally uses the code generator for evaluation and the code generator raises the wellsortedness errors. In the above case, Isabelle's type checker infers a type with a type variable for the term `mirror Typ`, namely `'a tree` where the type variable `'a` has sort `type`. Since a `'a tree` may contain values of `'a`, the code generator also tries to generate code for pretty-printing `'a tree`, which is implemented in the type class `term_of`. This fails however because the inferred type for `'a` is `type` and not `term_of`, and that is the reason for the well-sortedness error.

The simplest way to avoid the error is to give a monomorphic type explicitly. For example,

```
value "mirror Tip :: nat tree"
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you so match. If you know a reference or paper about the wellsortedness error, would you tell me where it is?

Comment: can't edit due to full edit queue :-(, so
`mirror Typ` -> `mirror Tip`
and
`value "mirror Tip :: nat tree"`
->
`value "mirror (Tip :: nat tree)"`